# How to Save _cache & _files Folders to Specific Directory

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I am using RStudio Version 1.2.5033 and R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12).

I creating RMarkdown (.rmd) files for my work then generating either PDF's or HTML files for display.

When I `knitr` the .rmd file to generate the pdf/html I get **2 additional folders/dir**,

```
fileName.pdf
fileName.html
# AND
/fileName_cache 
/fileName_files
```

If I have 10 .rmd files I get 20 garbage '_cache' and '_files' directories generated. Too Much Junk.

Is there a way to save these folders into a directory of my choosing, i.e. /junk/...????

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, but I can only find your post that describes the same issue. Did you ever find a solution? I can make the cache folder output where I like using: opts_chunk$set(cache.path = ...)), but the **files** folder doesn't follow suit. When I try subsequent knits, it fails because it can't find those file items (my figures).